# JPA how to delete an entity that is a target of onetoone with cascade remove

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with a onetoone relationship, A and B.  B entity is optional, can be updated and removed on it's own, but must always be linked to an instance of A.

So i have two JPA entities, A and B with a bi-directional relationship. THis is the one from A to B.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I can create a A and B, remove the A and both get deleted. good.

But because of the cascade from A to B,  if i `em.remove(b)` the delete doesn't get persisted.  Even if i do `a.setB(null)` first.

The only way to delete the optional entity, while keeping the cascade,  seems to be to use a new JPA2 feature, orphanRemoval=true. Call `a.setB(null)`, then persist A.

This means i can't do operations directly on B, it implies too strong of a composition relationship, all actions on B must be done via A.

But B is not an embedded object, it's a full blown Entity in it's own right, how can i delete it independently of A?

The best way seems to be to remove the cascade, and force users to make sure they delete any related objects separately  before they delete the A?  Enforced by a FK constraint in the B table.

This is such a straight forward case.  two related entities, the relationship is optional on one end, and mandatory on the other.

Oh, this is with hibernate 4.2.3-Final

Comment: `em.remove(b)` should work regardless of any cascade you have on A.  Have you tried a simple example where you just open a transaction, find an instance of B, call remove on it, and commit the transaction?  Just out of curiosity, do you set B's reference to A to null before you delete it?  I wouldn't think you'd have to but it may make a difference.

Comment: Hi,  yes i have tried that.  Just tried setting Bs reference to A to null first too and no change.  However just tried calling flush on the EntityManager after my delete and before my find.  Now it appears to be deleted.  So looks like a hibernate caching bug?

Comment: Did you change the flush mode to something other than FlushMode.AUTO?  If so, that is not a caching bug, that is how Hibernate is designed to work.

Comment: No i havent' changed the flush mode.  Hibernate is designed to return stale data from a find? It breaks basic transaction semantics.  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: If the flush mode is not on FlushMode.AUTO then Hibernate will not flush before a query.  When you modify an entity that modification isn't immediately pushed to the database.  Instead, all modifications are pushed to the database on the next flush.  With FlushMode.AUTO Hibernate will flush everything to the database before any query that isn't a basic find query.  Many people disable this as it can kill performance if you're doing a lot of queries and you know you haven't modified the data.

Comment: Oh, i'm doing a basic find.  Would be crazy if find(X) returned a result after you have just done delete(X) in the same transaction. So sounds like caching bug.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me too much if that were the case.  Try doing a find all and see if the entity comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Your current object design implicitly defined that one is more important than another. That is, one will have the foreign key to another.

To make them **equal**, you just define the JoinTable between them. Set cascade on both sides, and then everything will work as expected.

Example:

Document class

```
@Entity
public class Document extends ABaseEntity {

private Medicine medicine;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(
        name = "Document_Medicine",
        joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "MED_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
public Medicine getMedicine() {
    return medicine;
}

public void setMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
    this.medicine = medicine;
}
}
```

Medicine class

```
@Entity
public class Medicine extends ABaseEntity{
private Document document;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "medicine", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
public Document getDocument() {
    return document;
}

public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
}
}
```